# Last hit - Contest Programming

Tags: c

**Description**

Andre and Beto are playing a computer game that rewards the players in a very particular way: only the one that gives the last hit to defeat a monster will get all the gold that the monster leave behind. This implies that, although others players may have helped to defeat the monster, only the one who gives the last hit will be rewarded.

Andre is intrigued with this system, and asked your help. Given the number of life points of the monster, the damage that Andre and Beto can cause, and the lead time necessary between two consecutive attacks, find out who will give the last hit on the monster, defeating it and getting the reward.

At the beginning both Andre and Beto will attack, dealing At and Bt damage points, respectively. After each attack, both Andre and Beto have to wait exactly Ad and Bd seconds, respectively, before they can attack again. Whenever Andre and Beto can attack at the same time (as in the beginning), Andre has the priority and attacks first. A monster is defeated when its life points come to less or equal to zero.

**Input**

The first line contains an integer T, indicating the number of test cases to follow.

Each test case starts with four integers At, Ad, Bt and Bd (1 ≤ At, Ad, Bt, Bd ≤ 100), indicating the attack damage and the lead time between two consecutive attacks of Andre and Beto, respectively.

Following there will be an integer H (1 ≤ H ≤ 10000), indicating the number of life points of the monster.

**Output**

For each test case print one line containing one name, this being “Andre” if he's the last one to hit the monster, or “Beto” otherwise.

**My solution**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int absolute(int x)
{
    return (x < 0) ? -x : x;
}
int main()
{
    int t;
    int i,j; //for loops
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        int att,ad,bt,bd;
        scanf("%d %d %d %d",&att,&ad,&bt,&bd);
        int h;
        scanf("%d",&h);

        int aux = 0;
        int dt = absolute(ad - bd);// time difference

        if(ad <= bd) //andre is faster ... So andre hits in every loop and beto waits for his turn
        {
            while(1)
            {
                h -= att; //andre hits
                if(h <= 0)
                {
                    printf("Andre\n");
                    break;
                }
                if(aux++ == dt)
                {
                    h -= bt;//beto hits
                    aux = 0;
                    if(h <= 0)
                    {
                        printf("Beto\n");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else //beto is faster ... So beto hits in every loop and andre waits for his turn
        {
            while(1)
            {
                if(aux++ == dt) //first to hit is andre 
                {
                    h -= att; //andre hits
                    aux = 0;
                    if(h <= 0)
                    {
                        printf("Andre\n");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                h -= bt; //beto hits
                if(h <= 0)
                {
                    printf("Beto\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This solution gives WRONG ANSWER ... Someone has a hint ?

Comment: Does your code work correctly for the input given on this site? http://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/repository/UOJ_1627_en.html

Comment: run it under a debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a test case that you fail:

```
1
1 1 1 2
2
```

#### Your Output

```
Andre
```

#### I'm fairly sure the output should be...

```
Beto
```

#### Issues I'm seeing in your code

- Both Andre and Beto are supposed to attack on round 1
- If Andre attacks every 2nd round, and Beto attacks every 3rd round, your order of attacks will be incorrect.

#### Here's some working code:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);

    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        int at, ad, bt, bd, h;
        scanf("%d %d %d %d %d",&at, &ad, &bt, &bd, &h);

        int timestep = 0;
        while (true) {
            if (timestep % ad == 0) {
                h -= at;
            }
            if (h <= 0) {
                printf("Andre\n");
                break;
            }
            if (timestep % bd == 0) {
                h -= bt;
            }
            if (h <= 0) {
                printf("Beto\n");
                break;
            }
            timestep++;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Let's do some fuzzing with python

```
import subprocess
import random

def mine(inp):
    fd = subprocess.Popen("./mine", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return fd.communicate(inp)[0]

def yours(inp):
    fd = subprocess.Popen("./yours", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return fd.communicate(inp)[0]

def main():
    for i in range(100):
        inp = '1\n'
        inp += '{} {} {} {}\n'.format(random.randint(1, 100), random.randint(1, 100), random.randint(1, 100), random.randint(1, 100))
        inp += '{}\n'.format(random.randint(1, 1000))

        if mine(inp) != yours(inp):
            print inp.strip()
            print "My output:  ", mine(inp).strip()
            print "Your output:", yours(inp).strip()
            print

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### Then...

If we're confident about the output of my program. Which I am, then we can do use the fuzzing program to create random inputs that your program fails:

```
1
73 73 98 1
44
My output:   Andre
Your output: Beto

1
17 44 66 55
420
My output:   Beto
Your output: Andre

1
53 30 58 9
18
My output:   Andre
Your output: Beto

1
5 22 49 31
405
My output:   Beto
Your output: Andre

1
50 37 51 43
591
My output:   Beto
Your output: Andre

1
24 44 96 84
655
My output:   Beto
Your output: Andre

1
59 100 12 37
516
My output:   Andre
Your output: Beto

1
97 35 79 42
508
My output:   Beto
Your output: Andre

1
30 48 82 56
419
My output:   Beto
Your output: Andre

1
26 45 22 16
279
My output:   Andre
Your output: Beto

1
51 91 62 42
427
My output:   Andre
Your output: Beto

1
90 9 34 16
229
My output:   Beto
Your output: Andre

1
90 61 31 19
789
My output:   Andre
Your output: Beto

1
87 41 43 38
503
My output:   Andre
Your output: Beto

1
89 60 76 29
613
My output:   Andre
Your output: Beto
```

Comment: @HoboSapiens: The main issue with these online judge problems is that you are getting wrong answer to a dataset that you can't see.

Comment: My code was broken. I forgot to advance the `timestep`. I've updated with the corrected code and a new set of fuzzed outputs.